# By using ansible module sending command output to mail

Tags: ansible

```
---
- name: all
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the df command
      register: dfout
      command: "df -Th /home"

    - debug:
        var: dfout.stdout_lines

    - name: mail result
      mail:
        to: 'xyz@gmail.com`enter code here`'
        subject: "home location"
        body: "{{ dfout.stdout }}"
        when: dfout.stdout
```

unable to receive mails its showing like

```
==>fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (mail) module: when Supported parameters include: attach, bcc, body, cc,
 charset, headers, host, password, port, secure, sender, subject, subtype, timeout, to, username"}
```

Comment: ---
- name: all
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the df command
      register: dfout
      command: "df -Th /home"

    - debug:
        var: dfout.stdout_lines

    - name: mail result
      mail:
        to: 'xyz@gmail.com'
        subject: "home location"
        body: "{{ dfout.stdout }}"
        when: dfout.stdout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error message, it is clear that, `when` parameter is not supported by `mail` module. Error message also provide the list of supported parms for `mail` module.

Your Error message:

```
==>fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (mail) module: when Supported parameters include: attach, bcc, body, cc,
```

It appears that, you want to conditionally send the mail, for this you are using `when` module. This `when` should come at task level. **Notice the indentation.**

**Change this:**

```
- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: 'xyz@gmail.com`enter code here`'
    subject: "home location"
    body: "{{ dfout.stdout }}"
    when: dfout.stdout
```

**to:**

```
- name: mail result
  mail:
    to: 'xyz@gmail.com`enter code here`'
    subject: "home location"
    body: "{{ dfout.stdout }}"
  when: dfout.stdout                #<---make sure you use right syntax here too
```

More examples of `mail` module are present [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/mail_module.html#examples).